# Specify case statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can i convert this code to jquery

```
    var tmp = "";
for (var x in y) {
switch (x) {
case "abc":
document.getElementById("apple").innerHTML = "A";
break;
case "xyz":
document.getElementById("banana").innerHTML = "X";
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume variable x is an array? This would be an approach too:

```
$(x).each(function(key, value) {
    switch(value) {
        case "abc":
            $("#apple").html("A");
            break;
        case "xyz":
        $("#banana").html("X");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to have a little more detail, but how about this

```
var tmp = "";

for (var x in y) {
  switch (x) {
    case "abc":
      $("#apple").html("A");
      break;
    case "xyz":
      $("#banana").html("X");
    }
}
```

Comment: `$("#apple").html("A");` thats a jQuery object and `innerHTML` wont be present

Comment: Also, you do not need to `break` out of the last `case` of a `switch`, you're exiting it anyway.